# How do I place a video on an ASP.NET page and make it so that it will load in a timely manner?

Tags: vb.net, video, wmv, avi

I have an .avi video (500 MB-50 minutes) that I embedded using the following code in VB.NET:

```
<OBJECT width="360px" height="360px" CLASSID="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6" VIEWASTEXT>
<PARAM name="autoStart" value="False">
<PARAM name="URL" value="Video\Wellness_1.wmv">
<PARAM name="enabled" value="True">
<PARAM name="balance" value="0">
<PARAM name="currentPosition" value="0">
<PARAM name="enableContextMenu" value="True">
<PARAM name="fullScreen" value="false">
<PARAM name="mute" value="False">
<PARAM name="playCount" value="1">
<PARAM name="rate" value="1">
<PARAM name="stretchToFit" value="False">
<PARAM name="uiMode" value="full">
</OBJECT>
```

Worked fine except that it took approx 5 minutes to load.  Converted it to a wmv file (cutting it down to 300 MB) and it started playing instantly while it download.  Unfortunately there are some computers that will not play it for some reason.  It will load and the timer starts up as if the video is playing but there is just a black screen.
I ran some tests and determined that it's not a browser issue.

How can I upload a video that instantly plays on all computers?

Comment: You can surround it in `<pre>` tags, or indent by 4 characters to get code to show up with angle brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously at least some part of the video needs to be buffered before it can be played, so it makes no sense to ask for "a video that instantly plays on all computers".

> Unfortunately there are some computers that will not play it for some reason.

What are these "some computers"? They probably don't have a plug-in that is capable of playing WMV files. If you want to reach as wide an audience as possible, at the moment, Flash is your best bet. There are plenty of FLV converters available on the Internet that you can use to convert your AVI video into FLV.

HTML5 video is another option but not all browsers (specifically IE) support it yet.

Comment: I guess a better word than "instant" would be "in a few seconds"....which it does on some computers.  Is there any way that I can force them to download the plug-in?  If not I will look into Flash.  Thanks

Comment: You can't "force" them but most browsers will automatically give the user a choice to download missing plug-ins. In any case, WMV isn't a very good option if you would like Linux/Mac users to view your website.

Comment: They're all using Internet Explorer and all of the computers have Media Player 9.  I'll try flv and see what happens